# Measure page download time and render time with page subelements

Tags: javascript, ajax, performance

I am required to measure page load times for every visitor. I think best way would be injecting a javascript in the page for this purpose. But things are a little bit complex because I need every subrequest in page time measured seperately. The reponse times for requests going to 3rd party systems like CDN or Google need to be reported also. The page also has many ajax calls which are executed during page load. All these should be included and after a page done event other periodic ajax calls should not be included. And at the and all these measurements should be sent back to server for storing with (?XMLHttpRequest) . Anyone has done such thing before ? Any recommendations or sample scripts ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: while this is a start, it doesn't solve the fact that some content is asynchronously loaded. I don't know how to measure the loading time for images for example. It can be used in AJAX calls however.**

Here's a way you could do it. http://jsfiddle.net/45Lpwhyv/

```
function LoadingTimer() {
    this.timestamp = null;
    this.parts = [];
}

LoadingTimer.prototype.start = function (data) {
    this.stop();
    var i = this.parts.length;
    this.parts[i] = {};
    this.parts[i].data = data;
    this.timestamp = new Date().getTime();;
};

LoadingTimer.prototype.stop = function () {
    if (this.timestamp !== null) {
        this.parts[this.parts.length - 1].duration = (new Date().getTime()) - this.timestamp;
        this.timestamp = null;
    }
};
```

This class allows you to pass a data parameter to the timer, which can be a string like the name of the current part of the document that gets loaded. Now all you need to do is create an instance of LoadingTimer and call `.start("sectionName")` for each action you want to keep track of. If you want to stop a section without starting a new one immediately, just call `.stop`.

```
lt = new LoadingTimer();
lt.start("Time before first dialog gets closed.");
alert("Time will be checked when you will close this dialog.");
lt.start("Time before second dialog gets closed.");
alert("Let's do another one!");
lt.stop();
```

Obviously you could add extra methods to transmit the data to the server at some point, probably in JSON.

Comment: (Oh, and I hereby release this code in the public domain, not that it's worth much)

Comment: this might work with ajax calls I think. But how to measure loading of html elements like jpg,js,css,png etc..

Comment: Create a timer and start it in a script tag at the top of the head and then stop that timer in another script tag at the end of the body.

Comment: Yes but what if I want to measure seperate elements all jpegs seperately etc. Then I have to open script tag before and after the jpeg code ? Does the browser load them in same order as in html page ? Or it runs the scripts before it tries to load jpegs ? I think your answer is good but I want to get more information, please dont get me wrong. I also read  about Navigation Timing API in modern browsers. Can this be made without inserting timer tags all over the page?

Comment: You know what, I don't even think this would work for images as browsers load images in an asynchronous fashion, and even if it did work, it would make a very sloppy code. I don't know how to do it.